# jquery/javascript remove HTML tags but no content

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following code,

```
$(document.getElementById('messages_message-wysiwyg-iframe').contentWindow.document).keydown(function() {
        var iFrame =  document.getElementById('messages_message-wysiwyg-iframe');
        var iFrameBody;
        if ( iFrame.contentDocument ) 
        { // FF
            iFrameBody = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        }
        else if ( iFrame.contentWindow ) 
        { // IE
            iFrameBody = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        }
            console.info(iFrameBody.innerHTML);
    });
```

What I am trying to do if get the content of an iframe, but remove all the html tags that are not,

`b, strong, i, a, u, img`

However I do not want to remove any of the of the text, for example if the in the iframe there is the following,

```
<div class="box segment panel">
    <a href="http://www.google.com>hello world</a> 
    click this link and go far. 
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Placeholder"/>
 </div>
```

What would be return would be the following,

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">hello world</a>  
click this link and go far.
</a>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Placeholder" />
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, then _use jQuery_ instead of this crazy mix of plain JS and jq.  `$('#messages_message-wysiwyg-iframe')` instead of `document.getElementById(...)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var iFrame = document.getElementById('messages_message-wysiwyg-iframe');
var iFrameDoc = iFrame.contentDocument || iFrame.contentWindow.document;
$(iFrameDoc).keydown(function() {
    var iFrameBody = $("body", iFrameDoc);
    var cleared = iFrameBody.clone();
    cleared.find("*:not(b,strong,i,a,u,img)").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.replaceWith($this.contents());
    });
    console.log(cleared.html());
});
```

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/3jfrA/)

Comment: I _think_ this will fail to preserve the acceptable elements if they're nested inside other acceptable elements...

Comment: @Alnitak: Yes, I needed some time to get it to work. But now, each non-wanted element *in* the cloned body should be replaced by its own children, leaving the wanted html in the body.

Comment: @Bergi I would expect this to break for some element types that have specific nesting rules (e.g. table, ul)

Comment: I still don't think this'll work...  It's also very inefficient because it'll evaluate `$this.contents` for every non-matching node, when a simply DOM manipulation method would be more effective.

Answer (score 0):

With a regex:

```
iFrameBody.innerHTML=iFrameBody.innerHTML.replace(/<[^(b|strong|i|a|u|img)]\b[^>]*>/gi,"").replace(/<\/[^(b|strong|i|a|u|img)]>/gi,"");
```

The first replace removes the start tags, the second removes the end tags.

Note that there are a couple traps [when using regex to match html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg). But in this specific case it seems like a reasonable choice (cf. my comments on the other answers).

For the record, this is what I use to access an iframe's content document:

```
var doc=ifr.contentWindow||ifr.contentDocument;
if (doc.document) doc=doc.document;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my pure JS solution:

```
function sanitize(el) {

    if (el.nodeType !== 1) return;

    if (!/^(B|STRONG|I|A|U|IMG)$/.test(el.tagName)) {
        var p = el.parentNode;

        // move all children out of the element, recursing as we go
        var c = el.firstChild;
        while (c) {
            var d = c.nextSibling;  // remember the next element
            p.insertBefore(c, el);
            sanitize(c);
            c = d;                  // look at the next sibling
        }

        // remove the element
        p.removeChild(el);
    }
}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/WvJAx/

It works by (recursively) moving the child nodes of restricted tags out of their parent, and then removing those tags once they're empty.

Comment: same comment as for Bergi: this will break for some element types like table or ul.

Comment: @Christophe how?  Those elements will be removed by this code, but their internal text nodes left intact.

Comment: Ah - I see - you mean because an `<li>` might be temporarily moved outside its containing `<ul>` it'll be an illegal DOM.  Hmm...

Comment: if el=table how can you move head, body or even tr out of the element?

Comment: @Christophe that's a tricky problem - might require doing the moving from the leaf nodes first.  I think a minor adaption of my code could achieve that.

Comment: @Christophe it would work if the movement went all the way outside of the restricted tree, rather than to the immediate parent.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're a little confused about how to describe what you're trying to do. When you talk about "text", you're referring to the innerHTML/text node inside of a tag. What you're really looking to do, I think, is grab all of the specific content and the structure of the content, aka the children elements of the iFrame.

You can use jQuery's .text() method to get the text content of each element individually and save that before removing the actual tag from the DOM, if you want to lets say, get the text content of a span but you don't want the span to be in the DOM anymore, or you want to place it somewhere else in your document.

```
var elemText = $('span#mySpan').text();
$('span#mySpan').remove();
```

For what it looks like you're trying to do based on your sample HTML, you may want to look into jQuery's detach method: http://api.jquery.com/detach/

This will allow you to store the returned children elements to be appended somewhere else later.